# Get field information from a record/object selected as a lookup field

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I have a VF page that uses standard controller Account and an extension DonorSearchCon. When I select a Regional_Chapter_Name__c lookup field, from my VF page, I would like to query the record, and derive other field information for that record. Unfortunately, I get the following error:System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject.

Here is my code
VF Page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!acc.Regional_Chapter_Name__c}">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                   action="{!regionLookup}"
                   status="status"/> 
</apex:inputfield>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class DonorSearchCon {
public Account acc {get;set;}
private ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl;

    public donorSearchCon(ApexPages.StandardController std){
        stdCtrl = std;        
    }

    public void regionLookup(){
        Account acc=(Account) stdCtrl.getRecord();
       System.debug('acc:' +acc);
       Regional_Chapter__c regionInfo = [Select id, Regional_Chapter_Code__c from Regional_Chapter__c where Name=:acc.Regional_Chapter_Name__c];
        System.debug('acc.Regional_Chapter_Name__r' +regionInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your query:

```
Select id, Regional_Chapter_Code__c from Regional_Chapter__c where id=:acc.Id
```

Specifically here:

```
from Regional_Chapter__c where id=:acc.Id
```

The Account Id will never be the same as the Regional_Chapter__c Id

Try something like this:

```
from Regional_Chapter__c where Name = :acc.Regional_Chapter_Name__c
```

### Bonus Tip

I generally don't use `stdCtrl.getRecord()`. This will only pull in fields that you have defined on the page. While that may work for your case here, I would recommend a habit avoiding it.

I would also generally recommend a very minimal constructor. The one you have here is generally fine but I wouldn't put much more inside of it. Instead, I would add the `action` attribute to the VF page to call an init method: `action="{!init}"`

So the page would look like:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extension="DonorSearchCon" action="{!init}">
    <apex:pageMessages /> <!-- Used to display errors to the page -->
    <!-- Do not render the form if there is no account -->
    <apex:form rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(pageRecord))}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Regional_Chapter_Name__c}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                action="{!getRegion}"
                status="status"/> 
        </apex:inputfield>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Your extension would look like this:

```
public with sharing class DonorSearchCon {
    private ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl;
    public Account pageRecord {get;set;}

    public donorSearchCon(ApexPages.StandardController std){
        this.stdCtrl = std;        
    }

    // We use init methods because there are some tasks that cannot be 
    // performed in the constructor. This method is less limited in what it can do
    // but still gets called before the page actually renders
    public void init() {
        this.pageRecord = getAccount(this.stdCtrl.getRecordId());

        if (this.pageRecord == null) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(
                'No Account Found',
                ApexPages.Severity.FATAL
            ));
        }
    }

    private Account getAccount(Id recordId) {
        // Using a list here will prevent the List has no rows error
        // Instead, you will simply get an empty list.
        List<Account> accounts = [
            SELECT Id, Region_chapter_Name__c, 
                Regional_Chapter_Name__r.Regional_Chapter_Code__c
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id = :recordId
        ];

        // Check to make sure we have an account before trying to assign it
        return accounts.isEmpty() ? null : accounts[0];
    }

    public void getRegion(){
       // Using a list here will prevent the List has no rows error
       // Instead, you will simply get an empty list.
       // The important bit here is that Regional_Chapter_Name__c contains
       // the *Id* of the Regional_Chapter_Name__c record.
       // the Regional_Chapter_Name__r field contains the actual
       // Regional_Chapter_Name__c record and all of it's fields
       List<Regional_Chapter__c> regionInfos = [
           Select id, Regional_Chapter_Code__c 
           from Regional_Chapter__c 
           where Id = :pageRecord.Regional_Chapter_Name__c
       ];

       if (regionInfos.isEmpty()) {
           ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(
               'No Region Found',
               ApexPages.severity.FATAL
           ));
       } else {
           this.pageRecord.Regional_Chapter_Name__r = regionInfos[0];
           this.pageRecord.Regional_Chapter_Name__c = regionInfos[0].Id;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Actually, I already did, but now I am getting: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject.
if I run a debug, I am not getting any results:
    public void regionLookup(){
        Account acc=(Account) stdCtrl.getRecord();
        System.debug('acc:' +acc);
       Regional_Chapter__c regionInfo = [Select id, Regional_Chapter_Code__c from Regional_Chapter__c where Name=:acc.Regional_Chapter_Name__c];
        System.debug('acc.Regional_Chapter_Name__r' +regionInfo);
    }

Comment: If you already did it then update your code in your question.

Comment: I just did. Looks like my Account is not being instantiated.

Comment: Is `Regional_Chapter_Name__c` a lookup field?

Comment: Yes, it is a lookup field on the Account object, that looks into the Regional_Chapter__c object

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a detailed sample. That is as close as I can get you to where you need to be without just doing it for you.

Comment: Thanks. Trying it out.